# When should we better use class property in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

After Xcode 8 released, Objective-C has supported `class property`, but I am not familiar with this feature.

When are class properties initialized ?

Are they stored on `Stack`, `Heap` or `Static Area`?

What is the difference between class property and instance property?

When should we use them? Could you provide a scenario?

Comment: Read : https://useyourloaf.com/blog/objective-c-class-properties/

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, thanks but I just came from there, after reading it I don't think it really explain the questions I asked.

Comment: Basically its a minor improvement done to Objective-C to improve the interoperability of Objective-C with Swift. Especially when you generate Swift equivalent files of Objective-C file using bridges in your project the way class property in Objective-C is interpreted in Swift is now modified :) As a Objective-C developer what you get is you can now access your class property of Objective-C file using '.' notation like never before Example : User.community